# Rails Save Date Range to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form field that posts a date range in the format "05/14/2013 - 05/22/2013". My model has two separate date fields, `begin` and `end` for the respective beginning and end dates from the form field. What is the best MVC way to approach getting the date range into the correct fields?

I've been trying to manually deconstruct the date range in the controller's `create` method, but it looks like the updated params aren't properly seen in the model before the record is created.

EDIT:
The date range is coming in that format because I'm using Keith Wood's datepick, and it outputs the dates in a single input field.

What I've been trying to do currently is this (`contract` is the name of my model, and `dates` is the input date range:
  
    `beginDate = params[:dates].split("-")[0].strip()

    endDate = params[:dates].split("-")[1].strip()

    params.delete :dates

    params[:contract][:begin] = Date.strptime(beginDate, '%m/%d/%Y')

    params[:contract][:end] = Date.strptime(endDate, '%m/%d/%Y')

    @contract = Contract.new(params[:contract])`

... but these changes to params don't show up by the time the record is created and validated.

Comment: "but it looks like the updated params aren't properly seen in the model before the record is created" - can you expand on that? If you're in a controller's update method, and you pass the params along to a model method, it _will_ show the params as given by the user. My suggestion would be in the create and update you call a method on your model like `safe_update` or something where you do the extra work and try to update the model.

Comment: Actually another question is, why is the date range coming in in that format? If you have two text fields for entering dates, you'd get params like params[:begin] and params[:end] and then you wouldn't have to worry about manipulating a String.

Comment: I made edits to my question with more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a setter on your model which takes the field, splits it, and puts each part into the appropriate field.

```
def date_range=(val)
  begin_str, end_str = val.split(' - ')
  self.begin_at = Date.parse(begin_str)
  self.end_at = Date.parse(end_str)
end
```

This will work when called directly, or from a mass assignment method such as `update_attributes` or `create`. Make sure you add `date_range` (or the relevant param name) to `attr_accessible` if you already have this defined in your model.

I've changed the field names in my example, as`begin` and `end` should be avoided as field names, since one is a method and the other is part of the ruby syntax.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! I'll remember to do this kind of processing in the model from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual attributes to make the conversion from the date range text into individual dates at the model level. Add a setter and getter as below in the model,

```
def date_range_text
   return "#{start_date.to_s} - #{end_date.to_s}"
end
def date_range_text= val
  start_date_text,end_date_text = val.split[" - "]
  start_date = Time.zone.parse(start_date_text) unless start_date_text.nil?
  end_date = Time.zone.parse(end_date_text) unless end_date_text.nil?
end
```

And use data_range_text in your forms. For me information, check out the railscast below.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised

This is the best way to handle the difference between database structure and the user input forms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the `unless start_date.nil?` necessary if I am already validating for the presence of `start_date`?

Comment: It should have been start_date_text.nil?. My bad! From the controller when you call Model.new(params[:new]), it will call the data_range_text. And if the user has not filled in the field properly, the parse call will throw an exception. So its better you have it or use a rescue block.